# How to run webkit on Windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, visual-studio-2008, safari, webkit

Is it possible to integrate it with VS.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows. Contains Visual Studio instructions as well.